# Dynamic div height always 100%

Tags: jquery, css, height

How do I make a div always fill 100% of the space it has vertically? I have [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/Lb61va2m/) which shows how I did it with jQuery but can it be done with CSS?

```
var height = $('.content').height();
$('.sidebar').height(height);
```

PS we can't put a height on the container because we obviously need the sidebar to grow in height as content fills the .content area.

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't work, so I have no idea what you want. 100% of *what* space?

Comment: jQuery wasn't loaded on the Fiddle, my apologies. Check now. Also the commented jQuery has no relevance to the question. How to do it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, based in your fiddle, it would be enough with setting a fixed height of 700px to those `.sidebar` and `.content` divs, which I assume is not what you're looking for, so here you have an adaptive solution using your HTML markup with entirely different CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:700px;
}
.sidebar {
    background: grey;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    padding-bottom:5000px;
    margin-bottom:-5000px;
}
.content {
    background: #AEAEAE;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:500px;
    padding-bottom:5000px;
    margin-bottom:-5000px;
}
footer {
    clear:both;
    float:none;
    background: yellow;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
}
```

This solution will accept ANY height, both `.sidebar` and `.content` will take the height of whichever is the largest div to achieve an equal height column layout. However, if you feel you need some height for both divs, you can also do this:

```
.sidebar, .content{min-height:700px;} /* or whatever */
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzwo8vr6/) and play around to see how it works

Comment: Wow @Fabio! I would have never come up with this. Are there any caveats? You should make an entire blog post about this and post back here.

Comment: no, nothing, this is one of the ways to do this, not even the only one, just the one I tend to use the most (and I do this every day)

Comment: if you're having a 5000px HEIGHT sidebar, then add a padding-bottom:10000px and margin-bottom:-10000px. The important part is to have both padding-bottom and margin-bottom with huge values, where margin-bottom is the exact negative to padding-bottom

Answer (score 0):

your main point is to have the background expand over the entire height right? You don't care about the "actual" height of the aside-element, do you?

In that case, you can do what I did in this [fiddle update of yours](http://jsfiddle.net/7771w8me/2/):

Wrap aside and sidebar in a `<div class="main">`. As a div always expands to its biggest childs height, the height of it is automaticially the entire height no matter the viewport. Now add the following css to create a after-pseudolement behind the aside-box that has the entire expanded height and color it. Voilà, you have your background on the entire height:

```
.main {
    position: relative;
}
.main:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    background: gray;
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice @TC I'm going to give this a workout later on and get back to you here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really late, but I had this problem several times and I think in this case, `display: table-cell;` really shines: http://jsfiddle.net/yw6w562e/2/

Plus It's also really easy to realign them in smaller browser sizes with

`display: table-header-group;`
and
`display: table-footer-group;` (see fiddle Media Queries)

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
html, body, .wrapper, .sidebar { height: 100%; }
```

The outer wrapper has to be defined too.

Comment: `body { height: 100% }` is bad practice.

Comment: @scheisse_minelli and sometimes unavoidable. Got any sources to back up the 'bad practice' claim?

Comment: It is just my opinion. I wasn't trying to debate.

Comment: When ventilating opinions don't try to make them sound this 'authoritative'. While I agree to a certain extent that you shouldn't do it habitually, you sometimes need to to realize adaptive designs that have the footer stick to the bottom on less-than-viewport-high content. Making it sound like an undisputable fact will just confuse people.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I should have been more specific about the intentions of that comment. At any rate, nothing said on this site should be taken as indisputable fact in the first place. This is a great community, but it is still an open forum. Research should be done, even when provided with a convincing answer.

Comment: I actually agree, it is bad practice, but the request basically asks for it, unless you want to get "fancy" with the CSS.